# Using variable as file name in sqlcmd - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to print a table content into to a csv file using `sqlcmd`.

The file name is generated using a query :

```
set nocount on 
set ansi_warnings off

declare @report_date datetime
select @report_date = (select MAX(ddate) from table_to_export);

declare @ctl_file varchar(100)
set @ctl_file = 'BATCH_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), max(@report_date), 112) + '.CSV'

:out @ctl_file

select * from table_to_export where ddate = @report_date;

:out stdout
```

and executing the script from the cmd using

```
sqlcmd -i c:\temp\batch_report.sql -s"," -W -h-1 -f 65001
```

I'm currently getting an empty file named `@ctl_file` in the active directory.

Is there any way to pass a file name to `:out` command ?

I've tried using `bcp` but it wont output UTF encoding so it's not an option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
:setvar ctl_file "c:\temp\Batch_20140812.txt"
:out $(ctl_file)
select * from table_to_export where ddate = @report_date;
```

I am not sure how to set the file name within the script, but you could save a generic script and call it from sqlcmd, passing in the the filename as a variable.